# Solutions of non-linear equations in QFT and interpretation of particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, spacetime-dimensions, interactions, non-linear-systems

One of the simplest QFT model is $\lambda \phi^4$ theory.

$$
S = \int dt d^dx\; \left(\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{4!}\lambda \phi^4 \right)
$$

Equation of motion:

$$
\Box \phi = -\frac{1}{3!}\phi^3
$$

The equation is non-linear.

**What is known about solutions of such e.o.m.?**

What is physical interpretation of such solutions? How to match these solutions to spectrum of theory? Is it possible to relate some solutions to particles?

Note that my question about **any dimension of space time**. I think, that there are a lot about $d+1=2$ and $d+1 =4$, but unfortunately I never face with discussion of such questions.

Comment: To clarify: Are you asking about solution of the classical equation of motion, disregarding quantum field theory's operator-product issues? And are you asking about the case of Lorentzian signature or Euclidean signature?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly About classical equations. In Lorentzian signature. (If you know about Euclidean, please also give me information)

Answer (score 2):

There is one rather famous solution, called `Fubini instanton` by the name of it founder, discovered in 1976. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02785664

The abstract claims:

> A new approach to conformal invariant field theories is presented. The physical idea is to introduce a fundamental scale of hadron phenomena by means of a dilatation noninvariant vacuum state in the framework of a scale-invariant Lagrangian field theory. A new unconventional feature is that this programme can only be carried out if the «vacuum» state is not translation invariant. The «vacuum» is still invariant under a 10-parameter subgroup of the full conformal group but this subgroup does not coincide with the Poincaré group. A physical interpretation based on an appropriate averaging on an infinite ensemble of equivalent «vacuum» states allows to preserve energy momentum conservation, which is defined within a thermodynamical framework.

This solution describes the bounce solution, representing decay of the vacuum state.
There are generalisations to curved space - https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1521. However, these solutions were derived for $3+1$ case, and if you are asking about arbitrary dimension, I am unaware of any results there.

Moreover, there is a also a way, to obtain a solution of this equation in terms of formal series, which was invented by Rosly and Selivanov in 1996. Represent a solution of equation of motion in terms of formal series:
$$
\phi(x) = \sum_i \eta_i \phi_i e^{i k_i x} + \sum_{i, j}  \eta_i  \eta_j \phi_{ij} e^{i (k_i + k_j) x} + \ldots 
$$
Where $\eta_i$ are nilpotent non-commuting variables, such that $\eta_i^2 = 0$. The substitution in the equation of motion $\Box \phi = -\frac{1}{3!} \phi^3$ leads to the following recursion relationships:
\begin{align}
\phi_{i j} &= 0 \\
(k_i + k_j + k_k)^2 \phi_{i j k} &= - \frac{1}{3!} \phi_i \phi_j \phi_k
\end{align}
Where we fix initially $\phi_i$. And so on. Each coefficient for order say $n$ in these series would be a sum of all amplitudes with $n$-external particles, and the off-shell leg.